# Can I safely use `IO.File.GetAttributes` on a folder?

Tags: c#, attributes, io

My C# code detects changes in files and folders attributes, using the two following snippets:

```
// For files
    return (IO.File.GetAttributes(Source) != IO.File.GetAttributes(Dest))

// For folders
    IO.DirectoryInfo SourceInfo = new IO.DirectoryInfo(AbsSource);
    IO.DirectoryInfo DestInfo = new IO.DirectoryInfo(AbsDest);
    return (SourceInfo.Attributes != DestInfo.Attributes);
```

I noticed that `IO.File.GetAttributes` seems to work folder folders just as well, and so I was wondering whether I could drop the directory-specific part and just use the one-liner for both files and folders.

Is that possible ? Is reading `IO.DirectoryInfo.Attributes` equivalent to calling `File.GetAttributes`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans Passant already pointed out in his answer it is the same thing. The first inidcation is the common base class `FileSystemInfo` (`Attributes` property) that `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` share.

But is `File.GetAttributes()` and `DirectoryInfo.Attributes` also the same thing?

To answer that question have a look at the .Net Framework reference source code.

You can download the reference source code from here [.Net Reference Source Code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx). There you will find that both (`DirectoryInfo.Attributes`) and `File.GetAttributes()` both end up calling a internal function on the File class to get the attributes.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, same thing.  You can tell from the class inheritance.  The FileInfo and DirectoryInfo classes both inherit the non-abstract Attribute property from the abstract FileSystemInfo class.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in a way, directory is itself a file, just a special one. So it is logical, that common operations like GetAttributes work the directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you probably already answered your own question before you asked it.  But if you find some reason it doesn't work, you can always one line the other as well:

return new DirectoryInfo(AbsSource).Attributes != new DirectoryInfo(AbsDest).Attributes;

Comment: Precisely: I'm searching for someone with experience to confirm that there is no difference; this code is rather sensitive.

Comment: Only way to know for sure would be to compare the MSIL for the two functions.  I wouldn't be surprised if they were identical.